# Access свободное поле для ввода на ленточной форме

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Есть проект adp. В ней ленточная форма с продуктами, идея следующая: пользователь вводит в свободное поле количество товара, нажимает на кнопку "В корзину" по которой вызывается хранимая процедура и добавляет введенное количество товара в другую таблицу. Как вызвать хранимую процедуру и передать ей параметра из текущей записи я понял. А вот как сделать так, чтобы в свободном поле можно было писать различные значения не пойму. Сейчас если ввести в одно из них значение оно дублируется по всему столбцу. [image: Столбец со свободным полем]

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы значения свободного поля одной строки не дублировались во всей колонке?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными средствами Никак. Можно необходимое поле вывести в заголовок формы и тогда оно будет отображаться как одна колонка и изменяться(или нет) при переходе по записям[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А нестандартные способы есть?

Comment: Есть. Вставить в прост форму 2 подчиненные формы на 1 разместить поле и кнопку, на 2 с-но саму ленточную форму и перемещать эту форму средствами vba в нужное место при переходе по записям ленточной формы, но это уже тема для отдельного оффтопика. Можно попробовать погуглить такую реализацию.